# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:8000 FB UnitySDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-opengraph, facebook-unity-sdk

I have been trying to post some achievements in game with following code:
`FB.API(FB.UserId +"/"+achievementType,
       Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, 
       AchievementCallback,formData);`

but the result is sometimes posted on my activity log and sometimes it fails to post with the message 
"Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com:8000" while sometimes it is sucessful with post ID. I have tested the achievement files from facebook API explorer and also from POSTMAN plugin and it successfully posted it using both of them with post ID. But when I try to post the achievement from Unity3d it fails sometimes and works sometimes. Does anyone know what i am doing wrong while posting using UnitySDK? 
Note: I have hosted these files on Github. Example [AchievementFileLink](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zzbusterzz/AchievementTest/master/Achievements/Level20.html)
If anyone has suggestion please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround I found out for this is whenever the above error happens I again send the request in the callback method to post achievement and it gets published on my game activity successfully. This should not be the intended behaviour and is very bad practice but for time being ill take this as an answer.